# SQL Server- Adding check constraint for range of values

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, constraints

Ok, I have an issue creating an insert stored procedure. THis procedure will have to chekc the data entered, against one table, and insert in another. I have 3 tables designed, Time, Availability, and Contact Availability.This stored procedure will only focus on the Time and Contact Availability tables.

Time Table

TimeID     Time1   Time2

- 1. 8:30am 8:59am <----Both time columns are varchar and set to unique
- 2. 9:00am 9:29am
- 3. 9:30am 9:59am

The times are in half hour intervals until 530pm, which mean 18 time Id's.

Contact Availability Table

ID     Date    Time Availability

- 1094 2014-12-12  1   1
- 1094 2014-12-12  2   1
- 1094 2014-12-12  3   2
- 1094 2014-12-12  4   2
  etc...

The values for the time column coincide wit the timeID's from the Time table.

This is the stored procedure for searching a contacts availability with an inputted values:

```
  @date date,
  @time varchar(50),
  @lastname varchar(50)
  As
  SELECT    d.Date ,
            d.ContactID ,
            c.FirstName ,
            c.LastName ,
            a.Availability
  FROM      Daniel_Availability a
            JOIN Daniel_AvailabilityStatus d ON a.AVID = d.Availability
            JOIN Daniel_Time t ON d.Time = t.TID
            JOIN Contact c ON d.ContactID = c.ContactID
  WHERE     ( ( t.Time1 < @time )
              AND ( t.time2 > @time )
            )
            AND @lastname = c.lastname
            AND @date = d.Date
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is creating a stored procedure to allow a user to insert a new half hour time range in the Time table, but the new time range cannot duplicate or conflict with times already there. For example, the user should be able to add the range 7am-730am. The user should not be able to able add an 830am-9am range since it already exists, and the user should not be able to add 830am-845am since there is already an 830am-859am range. I hope what I'm asking makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that the time columns are stored as varchar. comparing 2 varchars (as integers, or "time" in this case will give the wrong results. varchar sort order will be something like 0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
So given this, 10:00am will be less than 9:00am. You'll have better luck if you prefix the times in your table with 0, so 08:00, 08:30...

A better approach would be to build up a proper datetime, and pass in a proper datetime to compare with, so you could try this...

```
  @StartDate DATETIME,  --<-- This full datetime you want to check like '2014-01-01 08:30'
  @lastname varchar(50)
  As

  DECLARE @CheckDate VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @Date, 121),
          @EndDate   DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, 30, @Date)

  SELECT    d.Date ,
            d.ContactID ,
            c.FirstName ,
            c.LastName ,
            a.Availability
  FROM      Daniel_Availability a
            JOIN Daniel_AvailabilityStatus d ON a.AVID = d.Availability
            JOIN Daniel_Time t ON d.Time = t.TID
            JOIN Contact c ON d.ContactID = c.ContactID
  WHERE c.lastname = @lastname
  AND d.Date = CONVERT(DATE, @StartDate)
  AND (
        @StartDate BETWEEN 
            CONVERT(DATETIME, @CheckDate + ' ' + t.Time1) 
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @CheckDate + ' ' + t.Time2)
  OR    @EndDate BETWEEN
            CONVERT(DATETIME, @CheckDate + ' ' + t.Time1) 
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, @CheckDate + ' ' + t.Time2)
  )
```

For this to work, you need to ensure that the date '2014-01-01' and whatever you have in your time table '8:30am' can convert to a valid datetime. i.e. SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01' + ' ' + '8:30am')